# Django Model hh:mm field

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model which I want to add a start time and an end time, hh:mm. I am not sure what field type is best for this, string with regex? The DateTimeField seems to just add the full date/time (as it suggest :)).

Any tips greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`models.DateTimeField` will solve your problem as it's default field to store date-time objects, although you need two separate fields for your start time and end time. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

**EDIT**

If you don't want the time, use `TimeField` instead. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to use it without the date though? I can't see a way in the docs to just have hh:mm

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `models.TimeField`?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#timefield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#timefield